# Generate an exact pivotal quantity for theta

Tags: self-study, distributions, confidence-interval

Given a random sample $x_1,...,x_n$ from $f(x|\theta)=\frac{\theta}{(x+1)^{\theta+1}}$, $x\ge0$

How to generate an exact pivotal quantity for $\theta$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. This appears to be a standard textbook style question. Please note the [faq discussion](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) relating to homework questions, and the tag-wiki info for the [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag (the two are synonyms).

So ... What have you tried? Do you know what a pivotal quantity is?

Answer (score 1):

Can you work out the distribution of $Y=ln(X+1)$?

Can you see a way to proceed from there?